# Asp.net Web Application individual accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, authentication, web-applications

I just created a new Asp.net Web Application with individual accounts authentication.

When the project is created, visual studio creates a temporary database with the tables for the authentication.

I would like to transfer these tables to my own sql server database. Is there a way to easily migrate from the temporary authentication database to an another one?

This is the connectionstring :

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Tango-20140628051144.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Tango-20140628051144;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and this is what i see in server explorer : 
[image]

Comment: Did your project create a LocalDb database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files created by a LocalDb database are simply SQL Server files. So you can quite easily attach them to your SQL Server installation.

In `SQL Server Management Studio`, right click the Database node in `Object Explorer`, select `Attach`.

In the popup window, browse to the MDF file created by your application and add it.

You should now have the database accessible in SQL Server.

Comment: hmm the it gives me an error message when I try to attach it (os error : access denied) even if it's on my D drive. Is there a sql server user that I need to grant access to the file system?